# AngularJS Ng-repeat and Duplicates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen few questions in SO discussing no duplicates allowed in ng-repeat. My question is little different. In my case I am confused because I am ***not getting the error even if there are duplicate objects in array***

Here is my HTML code

```
<table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td> {{ item.email}}</td>           
      </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the code for populating the array

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.items=[];

  $scope.items.push({
           "id":"1",
           "email":"a@b.com"});
  $scope.items.push({
           "id":"1",
           "email":"a@b.com"});

  $scope.items.push({
           "id":"2",
           "email":"x@y.com"});
  $scope.items.push({
           "id":"2",
           "email":"x@y.com"});


});
```

As per my understanding I should get the error and there are duplicate objects in array

However its getting rendered perfectly. Here is the plunker link

[ng-repeat-demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3oPCrW3RepxvWSZ1LB1?p=preview)

Obviously I am missing something basic. Can somebody point out my gap in understanding?

**EDIT**

Here is what in my application I was facing (only email ids are changed for obvious reason)

ExampleApp.filter("extractEmail", function (){

```
  return function(items){
    //console.log("test" + input[0].highlight.file[0]);
    var filtered = [];

    console.log(" items == " + items);


    angular.forEach(items, function(item){

      if (item){
        var obj = item.highlight.file[0].toString().match(/([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})/);

      if (obj) {
        //console.log(obj[0]);
        filtered.push(obj[0]);
      }

      }


    }); 

    console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
  }

});
```

my console.log prints `[“a@gmail.com", “a@gmail.com", “b@gmail.com", “b@gmail.com"]`

the error I get

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: x in clusterState| extractEmail, Duplicate key: string:a@b.com, Duplicate value: “a@b.com"
```

I updated the plunker with similar code. Not able to reproduce

**Second Edit**

The problem was with the version I was using:
Angular JS 1.0.x supported duplicates ***not able to reproduce***
http://plnkr.co/edit/qrOez7aZ7X1jsOrmkfiP?p=preview

With the later version ***able to reproduce***

http://plnkr.co/edit/q3oPCrW3RepxvWSZ1LB1?p=preview

Comment: This is one of the few times someone's complaining about not getting an error.

Comment: trying to understand  :)

Comment: This is certainly a good thing to try to understand. Angular is concerned about *equality*, not *equivalence*. `{id: 1}` may look like `{id: 1}`, but ``{id: 1} === {id: 1}` will return `false`, because it's creating a new Object for each. This is because Objects, and Arrays, are tracked by reference, not by value.  Now, if you did `var objX = { "id":"1", "email":"a@b.com"}`, and then `$scope.items.push(objX); $scope.items.push(objX);` you'll get the error (because `objX === objX` is `true`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects in javascript are compared by reference, not by value.
It really doesn't matter if the contents of an object is exactly the same as another one, if the references doesn't points to same object, they are different.
E.g.:

```
// In this case "var a" and "var b" points to different objects.
var a = {};
var b = {};

a == b; // false

// Here, they points to the same one
var a = {};
var b = a;

a == b; // true
```

If you need every entry to be distinct you must check every entry yourself.
Angular ngRepeat have a syntax variation that uses `track by` to let you decide which entry is distinct (or duplicated).

```
<div ng-repeat="entry for entries track by entry.id">{{entry.email}}</div>
```

Comment: And that's exactly what "track by" is for in Angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat.

Comment: @SkyWriter, you are totally right! `track by` is the way to go (editing my answer)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat "By default, ngRepeat does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements." It does not tell anything about references. Dont you think in that case documentation should be more clear

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder, if you pass an array like `[1, 2, 2, 3]` to ngRepeat it will break because the values are passed by copy, thus, `2` are duplicated. When you pass a array of objects the reference is clear (although the presentation isn't) distinct.

Comment: @NemoStain see my Update I am trying to reproduce it. Still have pasted the error

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder, in your Plunker you are loading Angular 1.0.x. The duplication check was introduced in Angular 1.1.5, that's why you can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 5):

The items are not considered equal because they point to different references.

If you were to track by ID, then you would get an error because the IDs are equal.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
  <td> {{ item.email}}</td>           
</tr>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aj_r/7d4n9z0u/